# How to have a CommonJS module execute its main() (as in Python)?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wonder if a method exists that would run a predefined function in a CommonJS module (as those used in Node.js). I wrote a couple of node modules that act as services/servers. I can run them from inside a "controller script" executing their respective main() method, but I'd like also to call them by itself, like we are used to do in python.

I think the way is to try to understand if the module has been REQUIREd or not.

Do you know how?

This is the equivalent in Python

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   print "Running standalone"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if (require.main === module) {
    console.log("running standalone");
}
```

[accessing the main module](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/all.html#accessing_the_main_module)