# CoffeeScript main?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, program-entry-point

I'd like to have a main function that is run only if my is not imported but
actually run and not imported.

Is there an equivalent to python's **name** == "**main**" in coffeescript?

Right now I'm using

```
is_main = process.argv[1]==__filename
if is_main
    main()
```

but I don't know if something more idiomatic exists, and I noticed
it did not work with older versions of coffeescript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to have a CommonJS module execute its main() (as in Python)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129829/how-to-have-a-commonjs-module-execute-its-main-as-in-python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Related JS question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129829/how-to-have-a-commonjs-module-execute-its-main-as-in-python/6129896#6129896)

`main()  if require.main is module`