# Run ES6 code only if module is executed directly

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I have been working with ES6 modules, and I was looking for a way to include code that runs *only* if the file is executed directly (as opposed to being imported by another file). In languages like Python that have had earlier native module support, this is easy: simply wrap the code in a `if __name__ == '__main__'` block and the code will only run if the file is executed directly. This is quite useful for things like attaching basic testing code to a library. I am curious if there is any way to do this with ES6.

Ideally, I would like to have something like this:

**File `a.js`**

```
export const pi = 3.1415
/* Some magical code here */
console.log("This only prints if you run a.js directly.")
```

**File `b.js`**

```
import {pi} from 'a';
console.log(pi);
```

So that one could execute the files and get the following outputs:

```
> somejsengine ./a.js
"This only prints if you run a.js directly."
> somejsengine ./b.js
3.1415
```

*I am also curious if such a solution exists for Node's CommonJS modules (as [Node.js still doesn't support ES6 style modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37132031/nodejs-plans-to-support-import-export-es6-es2015-modules))*.

Comment: You mean [How to have a CommonJS module execute its main() (as in Python)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6129829/218196) There is nothing in ECMAScript itself that provides such a functionality. Any solution you are looking for is environment specific (I guess Node.js in your case).

Comment: There's no way, and the way it should be done in Node depends on what exactly 'attaching basic testing code to a library' means. This is XY problem, the question should reflect real problem in order to get an answer that can solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there is a possibility for this in Node:
[Accessing the main module](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_accessing_the_main_module)

You can check, if the module is run directly with `require.main === module`.

```
if (require.main === module) {
    console.log("This only prints if you run a.js directly.")
}
```

Comment: ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead